# Different click action on the last item of a link list

Tags: jquery, click

Let's say we have the following list:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4 (different action)</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to assign a different click action on the last item of this list without any addition markup? I mean without having to add e.g a class="last" to the last item or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$('ul li a').slice(-1).click(function () {
   // Your general click handler here (All elements except last)
});

$('ul li:last-child a').click(function () {
   // Your more specific click handler here
});
```

Comment: :last is a much worse choice than :last-child

Comment: No problem, easy fix. Still works though. I don't use JQuery myself, so I don't have intimate knowledge about it performance-wise.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean a click event handler on **only** the last item:

```
$("ul > li:last-child").click(function() {
  //
});
```

If you want the click handler to act **differently** on the last one:

```
$("li").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":last-child")) {
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the :last selector.

```
 $(".yourUL li:last a").click(...);
```

This way you are adding the click event handler to the last li in the selected UL.

Comment: beware that this can cause problems when there are nested lists. Better use the direct child selector: `.yourUL > li:last`

Comment: agreed activa. :last doesn't tend to do what people expect.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the :last-child selector.

$('ul li:last-child').click(myFunc);